# Extract in csv - Excel formatting

Tags: data-loader

While extracting from Dataloader into a .csv file , a 20 digit number field from the source system is suffixed with 5 zeroes because excel suppresses any digit excess of 15.

I have come across a few suggestions for other versions of Excel but none for Excel 2010.

Anybody has any data formatting solution that worked ?

P.S Since during extraction to .csv , the digits are truncated , I assume no formatting with even make sense ?

Comment: I'm not certain I follow your question. CSV doesn't have the limitation, it's Excel that has the 15 character limitation. 15 character ID's are Case Sensitive, while 18 character ID's are not. If you have a number field, is it an integer or is it a decimal? Is the number being expressed as having been rounded to 15 significant chars perhaps for compatibility, then 10 to the power of 3 added to the end?

Comment: @crmprogdev- You are correct . For a 18 digit integer number , the last three digits are being replaced with 000 in Excel. Any other way where data can be extracted without this truncating limitation ?

Comment: This is a rounding error issue and a limitation of Excel. If you're exporting the data for use in Excel, that's precisely what you're going to get and there's no way around it other than to use a different spreadsheet program that supports more significant digits. Off-hand, I don't know of any, but perhaps someone else will.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment of crmprogdev, you should compare the raw .csv (with Wordpad/Notepad) and what you see in Excel. Sometimes the Locale settings of your own PC can also mess up what you see in Excel. Try setting your Locale settings to US/English.

Comment: The value appears correctly when I open the entire file .  But when I remove all the other columns , and try to open it through Word Pad , it again appears wrongly.